# How to append all url parameters from URL into all links on a page using php

Tags: php

Using php, my objective is to append whatever parameters are present on the url into all the anchors (links) on a page.

> - If a link already contains parameters: add the url query into the parameter.

Page url accessed:

> site.com/?location=brazil&sex=female

Page "site.com" code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <a href="https://example.com/">  HELLO1  </a>
<! ––I need it to become https://example.com/?location=brazil&sex=female ––> 

 <a href="https://example.com/?human=yes">  HELLO2  </a>
<! ––I need it to become https://example.com/?human=yes&location=brazil&sex=female ––> 

<?php

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I've done it in javascript but ran into a few problems. Can somebody help me with a php code? Regards.

Comment: do u mean that you wanted to add the parameters of current page to all anchor tag hyperlinks present in that page?

Comment: Correct. If user access with ?zip=123 I want all the hyperlinks to also have this parameter.

Comment: Ok, i'll read the documentation about $_GET and loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I hope this will help you out   

<?php  
              //to get current url
              $url = "https://";   
            //Append the host(domain name, ip) to the URL.   
            $url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];   
            
            //Append the requested resource location to the URL   
            $url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    
            //for example the url i considered
            $url_example = 'https://example.com?q=string&f=true&id=1233&sort=true';

              //explode function will breakdown string in array
            $host = explode('https://example.com?', $url_example); //here replace $url_example with $url as i used for demo purpose only
    
            // accessing the second part of array
            echo $host[1]; //for checking
    ?>   
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <a href="https://example.com?<?= $host[1] ?>">Hello!</a>
    
    <a href="https://example.com?human=yes&<?= $host[1] ?>">Hello2</a>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Atomankion, thank you for the response. Do I also need to change  the 'https://example.com/' on explode?  I believe I committed a mistake on my example above because I've used the same url for the current page and for the hyperlinks: it should have been 'site.com' for the current page and 'example.com' for the hyperlinks. (does your suggestion still work if the hyperlinks are a different domain). Again, thank you so much for helping me, I'm testing it out. Regards.

Comment: i used explode function in order to split the URL into two halves one is page URL and second is parameters passed to URL so in place of **example.com**  change it with your page URL **site.com** and that will work.

Comment: One problem is that in the second example, when a parameter is already set, the second parameter also gets a "?" so it wrongly becomes https://example.com/human=yes&?zip=123. But it's mostly solved. Thank you.

Comment: is it **https://example.com/human=yes** or **https://example.com?human=yes**

Comment: Sorry! It should be example.com?human=yes  or example.com/?human=yes

Comment: i hope than your problem solved and i just made some minor changes in the code just go through it